# Huffman coding, write to filr using bits

Tags: c++, encoding

I wrote Huffman algorithm, it builds tree.
After I have sequence of 1 and 0 in string.
How to get them into file by bits? In the internet i found code:

```
ofstream fout("out.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
for each(char s in bnr)
{
    buf = buf | s << (7 - count);
    count++;
    if (count == 8)
    {
        count = 0;
        fout << buf; 
        cout << buf;
        buf = 0;
    }
}
```

So for exmple I have string "ab", using algorithm I get string "01", the code below doesn't put anything in the out.txt, that is the problem. 
Please describe the bit opertions for this task, or describe a different way to write bits to file.

I'm trying not to use STL, because my teacher forbids it.

Comment: `smth`? Huh? what's that?

Comment: Looks like C++-CLI code, not C++.

Comment: smth - i mean the encoded string, so what about real problem?)

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have much to do with Huffman coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the string consists of ascii characters '0' and '1', then you need to make a slight change to the example code. This example has most of the logic.

```
    unsigned char buf = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != '\0')
    {
        buf = buf | ((s[i++]-'0') << (7 - count));
        count++;
        if (count == 8)
        {
            count = 0;
            fout << buf; 
            buf = 0;
        }
    }
    if(count != 0)
        fout << buf;
```